# How to use findOneBy with withDeleted in TypeOrm

Tags: node.js, express, typeorm

I use `TypeOrm` for my `express` app.

I have a `Category` entity with `soft delete`.

```
@DeleteDateColumn()
deletedAt: string
```

I write a **route** for `force delete`.`force delete` will delete a `softDeleted Category`.

By default in `TypeOrm`, when I `remove(category)` a `Category`, It will return `deleted Category` *(`delete()` does not)*. It is very usefull for something like `undo` *(I may be use it)*.

But I can not use `findOneBy` with `withDeleted`. If I only use `findOneBy`, it will return `null` for `soft deleted Category`. I tried to find some docs but I cann't find out.

In fact, I can do that with more code, more handle, like:

```
const category: Category[] = await categoryRepository.find({
  where: {
    id,
  },
  withDeleted: true,
})

if(category[0]) {
  // handle force delete
  const deletedCategory = categoryRepository.remove(category[0])
  //
}
```

but I don't really like this.